# Php contact form working only for hotmail - The form is working

Tags: php, forms, validation, contacts

Recently, I've developed a simple contact form using PHP and posted it online. I noticed that this form is only sending the E-mail when the sender write an e-mail with @hotmail.com domain.

Writing any other email like gmail or yahoo or any other domain is not working. It says that your message is sent, but i don't receive the E-mail.

PHP code:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$formcontent=" From: $name \n E-mail: $email \n Message: $message \n";
$to = "yasserkabbout@gmail.com";
$subject = "Contact Form - RESUME";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($to, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");

?>
```

Do you know how to solve this problem ?

Comment: My form is working i'm not having problems. It's just that it works for some domains and not others.

Comment: Are the domains on the same server?